# Typescript create string literal union type from array in object

Tags: typescript

my goal is to create a string literal union type from an array in an object.

I know how to create a union type from an array, like so

```
const genderArr = ["female", "male"] as const;
type Gender = typeof genderArr[number]; // "female" | "male"
```

How can I achieve the same for an array inside of an object

```
const QuestionnaireOptions = {
    GENDER_OPTIONS: ["female", "male"],
    SIZE_OPTIONS: [
        "s",
        "m",
        "l",
    ],
};

type Gender = ??
```

I could not find any resource / similar stackoverflow post so far.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [index access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a specific property of the container object:

```
const QuestionnaireOptions = {
    GENDER_OPTIONS: ["female", "male"],
    SIZE_OPTIONS: [
        "s",
        "m",
        "l",
    ],
} as const;

type Gender = typeof QuestionnaireOptions['GENDER_OPTIONS'][number]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAigVwKbQJbjAQ1QJyQeQAcp1IYBeGAbwFgAoGRmAcQFEA5AEVYCUB9fAAUAKgEl87AMoAuGAG0ARADMkAW0wAbJAoA0MBeq0KAujvpMYk0QC1WAkeKmy55i0wURdrt-tVeGPvoa-ham9AC+MJgQMKCQUADc9PRQAJ6ESCxIYAAmSDgUMGkZIErwyGgY2HhEJOAQcgDkbFy89mISko3GcmAIqgBG+cZAA)

Comment: I think worth adding [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) link

Comment: Missed to answer, thank you!!